# Promise in Javascript working with ".then()" but not with async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, protractor, es6-promise

**Function call:**

```
var oldBalance =  objToPageObjectFile.getBalance();
//objToPageObjectFile is object referring to a file where "getBalance()" is defined.
```

**Function definition:**

```
Works with ".then()"

 this.getBalance=function()
 {
    var storeBalance = readBalance.getText().then(function(balance){
        return balance;
 });

    return storeBalance;
}
```

Not working with async/await

```
this.getBalance() = async function()
{
    var storeBalance;
    storeBalance = await readBalance.getText();
    return storeBalance;
}
```

**Error is :**
Error: TypeError: this.getBalance is not a function

Why am I getting error with async/await? I am using InteliJ IDE.

Comment: You have a **typo**: `this.getBalance() = async function()` remove `()` after `this.getBalance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be the brackets after `getBalance`, try this:

```
this.getBalance = async () => {
  // Your code goes here
}
```

**Update**

Edited the code to focus on the solution to the error in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.

Comment: There is no reason to do `return await fn()`.  Just do `return fn()`.  Same result, but less code.  The `await` is useless in this specific circumstance.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/1442) to understand why I think the opposite and believe `return await` should _always_ be used. Especially for beginners, but in my opinion for everyone.

Comment: that code does not make sense, in the end you still return an promise, you could also go directly without `async` and just return `return readBalance.getText()`